R code not recognizing error (tryCatch) when webscraping
I'm trying to scrape data from Google Scholar. I don't have much experience with coding and scraping, so I've run into many issues. I made a similar post here, except I have a new problem. When I receive the error message
"Warning: Response code 429. Google is rate limiting you for making too many requests too quickly."
I want to pause my loop and wait 15 minutes for the timeout to expire. I've tried putting in a tryCatch(), but it isn't recognizing the 429 error. I know this because the console just outputs the 429 error over and over again instead of pausing for 15 minutes. I have no idea why it isn't working, since it looks correct. The following is the console output:

Warning: Response code 429. Google is rate limiting you for making too many requests too quickly.Warning: Response code 429. Google is rate limiting you for making too many requests too quickly.Warning: Response code 429. Google is rate limiting you for making too many requests too quickly.

My code is currently

scholar_ids <- character(nrow(info))

last_successful_iteration <- 0  # Initialize last successful iteration

i <- 1  # Start at the first row

while (i <= nrow(info)) {
  id <- NULL
  
  tryCatch({
    id <- get_scholar_id(last_name = info$last_name[i],
                         first_name = info$first_name[i],
                         affiliation = "School Name")
    last_successful_iteration <- i  # Update last successful iteration
  }, error = function(err) {
    cat("Error message:", err$message, "\n")  # Print the error message
    if (grepl("429", err$message)) {  # Check if the error contains 429
      cat("Timeout. Pausing for 15 minutes.\n")
      Sys.sleep(900)  # Pause for 15 minutes (900 seconds)
      i <- last_successful_iteration  # Restart the loop from the last successful iteration
    } else {
      stop(err)  # If it's not error 429, stop and display the error
    }
  })

    scholar_ids[i] <- id  # Store the ID in the vector

    # Increment the loop variable to move to the next iteration
    i <- i + 1
  }
  
  # Random sleep to avoid hitting rate limits
  sleep_time <- runif(n = 1, min = 10, max = 12)
  Sys.sleep(sleep_time)
}

where "info" is a data frame with a column for first name and last name. I plan to later add a column of Google IDs to the info data frame once I get them.
I've looked at many sources online on how to catch errors and my code lines up with theirs, but obviously something is not quite right.
When I get the 429 error, I would like it to say "Timeout. Pausing for 15 minutes.\n" as listed above. My code does not output this at all even when I get the 429 error.

Wouldn't it be better to avoid hitting the rate limit? Just Sys.sleep after each iteration of the loop.

Based on your console output, it seems like its not ever hitting the error branch/printing an error message. It's possible that you need add handling for warnings to your tryCatch branch. Similar to
error = function(err) { ... } 

you can try adding
warning = function(warn) { ... } 

so it looks something like this:
tryCatch({
    id <- get_scholar_id(last_name = info$last_name[i],
                         first_name = info$first_name[i],
                         affiliation = "School Name")
    last_successful_iteration <- i  # Update last successful iteration
  }, error = function(err) {
    cat("Error message:", err$message, "\n")  # Print the error message
    if (grepl("429", err$message)) {  # Check if the error contains 429
      cat("Timeout. Pausing for 15 minutes.\n")
      Sys.sleep(900)  # Pause for 15 minutes (900 seconds)
      i <- last_successful_iteration  # Restart the loop from the last successful iteration
    } else {
      stop(err)  # If it's not error 429, stop and display the error
    }
  }, warning = function(warn) { cat("Warning branch\n") })

although without knowing the details of the return object, its possible the message being printed to the console is not a true R error/warning (e.g., is just a print statement).
